# How to create a copy of an array with unusual typecode in Jython

Tags: python, arrays, jython

I am using the Java library nom-tam-fits for reading and writing FITS files within Jython 2.7.  I need to manipulate the underlying data arrays in the FITS HDUs however I am not able to make copies of the arrays using the `copy` library.

```
>>>from nom.tam.fits import Fits
>>>import copy
>>>f = Fits('example_image.fits')
>>>data = f.getHDU(0).getKernel()
>>>new = copy.deepcopy(data)
TypeError: array() argument 1 must be char, not str
```

Further exploration reveals that `data` is a 2d `array.array` with an unusual typecode `[I`, which is interpreted as a `str`.

```
>>>type(data)
<type 'array.array'>
>>>data.typecode
'[I'
>>>data[0].typecode
'i'
```

I cannot make a manual copy either due to the same issue of the typecode being a `str` not a `char`.

```
>>>import array
>>>new = array.array(data.typecode)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: array() argument 1 must be char, not str
```

Is there a way to create this type of `array.array` within Jython to create a copy or is this error a result of converting Java classes to Python classes and the work around would be to manipulate the data within Java itself?

Comment: Why are you trying to make an array out of the type code?

Comment: According to the documentation to create a new array object: `class array.array(typecode[, initializer])`.  The array is initialized with a specific typecode.

Comment: I see. It doesn't like the 2-character typecode. "char" means 1 character.